# Issues with the R.java file

Tags: java, android, build, r.java-file

When I made my android app and ran it for the first time then the R.java file wasn't automatically generated. Then, I first cleaned the project and later on autobuild it and the R.java file was regenerated. But now I am getting error on

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);//main can't be resolved or is not a field.
```

So, how to overcome this error else tell a better way to autogenerate the R.java file?

Comment: check if you have `import android.R;` if so remove it. Check the resource file for errors. if so fix it and clean and build the project

Comment: @Raghunandan, I have already done that but it doesn't help.

Comment: R.java will not be generated if you have errors in your resource file. Did you check that?. If that doesn't help. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

try out these things

if you have this in your imports:

```
import android.R;
```

remove it and then add

```
import your.application.packagename.R;
```

and clean and build the project

go through the documentation for details

As described at [https://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20140325152640/http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html):

> Note: Eclipse sometimes likes to add an "import android.R" statement at the top of your files that use resources, especially when you ask Eclipse to sort or otherwise manage imports. This will cause your make to break. Look out for these erroneous import statements and delete them.